# ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode

Tags: python

Скажу сразу - я новичок в Python, Пишу скрипт для создания зашифрованных под AES256 QR-кодов, решил её допилить с использованием OpenCV (Для считывание QR-кодов напрямую, из изображения)- до этого всё работало (шифровало, дешифровало) а теперь вот такая ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\cryptqr\cryptqr.py", line 109, in <module>
    decrypted = decrypt(str(data).encode(), (password))
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\cryptqr\cryptqr.py", line 23, in decrypt
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:]))
  File "D:\games\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py", line 246, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Data must be padded to %d byte boundary in CBC mode" % self.block_size)
ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Сам код у меня такой:

```
import qrcode
import cv2
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
BLOCK_SIZE = 32
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE).encode()
unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]
def encrypt(raw, password):
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    raw = pad(raw)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))
 
 
def decrypt(enc, password):
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
    iv = enc[:16]
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:]))


def read_qr(img_name):
  import cv2
  img = cv2.imread(img_name)
  return img
print("CryptQR v1")
print("==============================================")
while True:
  lang = input("Choose the language - 1)Russian  2)English: ")
  if (lang == "1"): #Русская часть - Russian part
    a = input("Выберите режим - 1)Создание QR  2)Открытие QR: ")
    if (a == "1"): # Режим создания QR - QR Creating Mode
      while True:
        data = input ("Введите текст (до 512 символов): ")
        if (len(data) > 512):
          print("==============================================")
          print("Вы не можете ввести больше 512 символов!")
          print("==============================================")
          continue
        else:
          while True:
            password = input ("Введите пароль (От 16 до 32 символов): ")
            if (len(password) < 16):
              print("==============================================")
              print("Вы не можете ввести меньше 16 символов!")
              print("==============================================")
              continue
            elif (len(password) > 32):
              print("==============================================")
              print("Вы не можете ввести больше 32 символов!")
              print("==============================================")
              continue
            else:
              encrypted = encrypt(str(data).encode(), str(password)) 
              filename = "cryptqr.png"
              end = encrypted.decode()
              img = qrcode.make(str(end))
              img.save(filename)
              print("==============================================")
              print("QR-код создан!")
              print("==============================================")
              input()
              break
          break
    elif (a == "2"): #Режим открытия QR - QR Opening Mode
      a = input("Выберите режим открытия - 1)Из текста  2)Из изображения: ")
      if (a == "1"):
        data = input("Введите зашифрованный текст с QR-кода: ")
        while True:
          password = input("Введите пароль от данных (От 16 до 32 символов): ")
          if (len(password) < 16):
            print("==============================================")
            print("Вы не можете ввести меньше 16 символов!")
            print("==============================================")
            continue
          elif (len(password) > 32):
            print("==============================================")
            print("Вы не можете ввести больше 32 символов!")
            print("==============================================")
            continue
          else:
            decrypted = decrypt(str(data).encode(), (password))
            end = decrypted.decode()
            print("==============================================")
            print("Расшифрованный текст: " + str(end))
            input()
            break
      elif (a == "2"):
        print("ВНИМАНИЕ! Вы должны переименновать файл в cryptqr.png, и положить в одну директорию с этим скриптом")
        input("Нажмите ENTER что-бы продолжить ")
        while True:
          password = input("Введите пароль от данных (От 16 до 32 символов): ")
          if (len(password) < 16):
            print("==============================================")
            print("Вы не можете ввести меньше 16 символов!")
            print("==============================================")
            continue
          elif (len(password) > 32):
            print("==============================================")
            print("Вы не можете ввести больше 32 символов!")
            print("==============================================")
            continue
          else:
            data = read_qr("cryptqr.png")
            decrypted = decrypt(str(data).encode(), (password))
            end = decrypted.decode()
            print("==============================================")
            print("Расшифрованный текст: " + str(end))
            input()
            break
    break
  elif (lang == "2"): # Часть на на английском - English part
    while True:
      a = input("Choose mode - 1)Create QR  2)Open QR: ")
      if (a == "1"): # Режим создания QR - QR Creating Mode
        while True:
          data = input ("Enter text (up to 512 characters): ")
          if (len(data) > 512):
            print("==============================================")
            print("You cannot enter more than 512 characters!")
            print("==============================================")
            continue
          else:
            while True:
              password = input ("Enter password (From 16 characters): ")
              if (len(password) < 16):
                print("==============================================")
                print("You cannot enter less than 16 characters!")
                print("==============================================")
                continue
              elif (len(password) > 32):
                print("==============================================")
                print("You cannot enter more than 32 characters!")
                print("==============================================")
                continue
              else:
                encrypted = encrypt(str(data).encode(), str(password))
                filename = "cryptqr.png"
                end = encrypted.decode()
                img = qrcode.make(str(end))
                img.save(filename)
                print(str(end))
                print("==============================================")
                print("QR code created successfully!")
                print("==============================================")
                input()
              break
          break
      elif (a == "2"): #Режим открытия QR - QR Opening Mode
        data = input("Enter encrypted text from QR code: ")
        while True:
          password = input("Enter the data password (16 to 32 characters): ")
          if (len(password) < 16):
            print("==============================================")
            print("You cannot enter less than 16 characters! ")
            print("==============================================")
            continue
          elif (len(password) > 32):
            print("==============================================")
            print("You cannot enter more than 32 characters!")
            print("==============================================")
            continue
          else:
            decrypted = decrypt(str(data).encode(), (password))
            end = decrypted.decode()
            print("==============================================")
            print("Decrypted text: " + str(end))
            input()
      else:
        continue
    break
  else:
    continue
```

Пожалуйста объясняйте проще - я новичок

Comment: Данные должны быть дополнены до 16-байтовой границы в режиме CBC. Перевод гугл переводчика. Дополните данные до 16 байт например нулями. У вас данные слишком маленького размера получаются.

Comment: Я записал текст который больше чем 16 байтов, и раньше всё работало даже в 1 символ, шифровало, дешифровало

Comment: Странно, что требуется паддинг до 16-ти байтов при использовании 32-х байтового ключа. Не могли бы Вы сократить код до минимума, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#cbc-mode - *expects data to have length multiple of the block size (e.g. 16 bytes for AES)* - какая-то очень странная библиотека. AES бывает и с блоками в 32 байта и в 64 байта. В той же документации предлагается использовать `Crypto.Util.Padding` для паддинга.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Тут сократить то особо и не получиться - так работает, при QR-коду уже нет - да и я вчера вроде решил эту проблему, но сегодня опять не работает